# Parent and Child

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to solve a particular business question and I'm not sure how it translates into drupal sematics, so please excuse me if this has been asked before.

I want to use a series of content types to capture user feedback on different engineering aspects of a project: the structure is pretty much

-> project

--> milestone

---> current technology set used

---> precieved highest risks

because the cardinality of the children is always >1, I think I need to use a separate content type for each.

Can anyone tell me how I add links to create a child object when viewing the parent, ie. create a new milestone for this project....  I can't seem to find a starting point in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try one of these modules

1. [References](http://drupal.org/project/references)
2. [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation)

> Relations are entities and can therefore have fields. This makes
>   Relation the most flexible and powerful relation model out there.

1. [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

> Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities:

If youre looking for some Project management tools try these

[Project Management](http://drupal.org/project/pm)

[Open Atrium](http://drupal.org/project/openatrium)